# Semantic-UI :: Downloadable font - bad linegap

Tags: css, semantic-ui

*,

I get in my Firefox console the following error while loading the html page below (see snippet code).
And in the other hand the Chrome's console says nothing... >_>

```
downloadable font: OS/2: bad linegap: -32 (font-family: "Dropdown" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
source: data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,<<...>>
semantic.css:30715:12
```

But moreover the `dropdown` doesn't work (~doesn't display `items`) at all on both browsers.

Have you any idea why and how to fix it?

Thks

- [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com) js/css - 2.2.10
- jQuery v3.2.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css'>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
            <input name="gender" type="hidden">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="default text">Gender</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My issue is likely the same as that one: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your HTML is valid markup for the [Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) module, you still need to initialise it with JavaScript.

Read more: [Dropdown - Initializing Existing HTML](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#initializing-existing-html)

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css'>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
            <input name="gender" type="hidden">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="default text">Gender</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'Bad Linegap' error hasn't prevented the dropdown working for me.

Comment: I completely forgot the initialization, it works better then ;-) -thks
Unfortunately the console error persists, did you get the same error message?

Comment: I did ... many a time, but I've just got used to ignoring it as it had no noticeable effect.

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding the console error:

You're definitely not the only one with this problem.

**The bad news** is that Semantic UI/Fomantic UI* is broken here (hence the error).

**The good news** is that it seems to work anyway.

#### The Issue:

Semantic UI (and it's successor Fomantic UI) uses [`data urls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to encode a tiny font file for the arrow characters used in the [dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) module. The same technique is also used in the [checkbox](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html) and [accordion](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html) modules as well as the [step element](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/step.html).

I'm not exactly sure here, but there appears to be something wrong with the font encoding in the data url. If you look at [the CSS for dropdown](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/dist/components/dropdown.css), you can see the font encoding in the `@font-face` directive towards the end of the file.

It's basically defining a custom font just for the icons used in each control (e.g., the arrow in the dropdown input). I tried to decode the UTF-8 base64 into a font file, but my OS won't recognize the font.

But other than the error message, you won't really have an issue with it.

---

* Semantic UI seems to be dead at this point (at v2.4.2). It's been forked over to [Fomantic-UI](https://fomantic-ui.com/) and is now at v2.8.8 with lots of fixes and active development. Unfortunately, it also has this same issue.